# Unable to authenticate services

Tags: android

i need to authenticate my services with username and passwor i have try [**this**](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/example-for-restful-web-service-authentication-t51172.html) but not get sucess can you help me

when i print inlog cat i got ::

**Update 3 ::**

```
11-04 16:07:58.767: INFO/System.out(1531): Returned ======>>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Code ::**

```
   DefaultHttpClient UserIDclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                 List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","password"));
                 UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps,HTTP.UTF_8);
                 httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
                 HttpResponse response = UserIDclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                    Returned = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    System.out.println("ans is :: "+ Returned);

            System.out.println("Returned ======>>> "+Returned);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Thing:**

Check whether the "returned" string is null or not.

**2nd Thing:**

One thing i notice that you have written below lines for twice, what is the need to call execute() method before passing username and password:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Returned = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Instead your code should be:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Your DATA
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", "username"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "password"));

        response.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(post);

        if(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
            System.out.println("=========> Response => "+iStream_to_String(resEntitiy.getContent()));  

        }
```

// You can get iStream_to_String from [here](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/android-inputstream-to-string-conversion/).

Comment: check the updated code, run it and just check what you get at console.

Comment: 11-04 15:46:38.347: INFO/System.out(1381): Returned ======>>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: @Dr.nik i am sure you are not knowing how to make a webservice call? you were facing problem in same.

Comment: no its not that you also shown other to url in which i got sucess to pass and display very well also. but i got problem in `auth` onl. now i got solution by pass parameter directly in url like `url ...?userid=""&pass=""`